# Where I can deploy my project on nuxt.js except Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using Google App Engine for deploying my nuxt js projects (ssr mode), but it's a bit expensive for me and I'm looking for some alternatives.
Which other services do you use for deploying your nuxt js projects (ssr mode) except Google App Engine and why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to check the official Nuxt.js documentation. especially the deployment part of the [FAQ](https://nuxtjs.org/faq).

Personally I think the easiest is on heroku :

- Nuxt doc : https://nuxtjs.org/faq/heroku-deployment
- Heroku doc : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

If you have a small app you can stay in the free tier for ever.

Comment: Heroku looks good for me. But can I deploy exactly projects on nuxt in universal mode or it's only for static websites?

Comment: Yes you can totally deploy nuxt in universal mode (I have a nuxt production website in universal mode on Heroku)

Comment: Great thank you)
Can you tell how much do you pay for it? 
Because I'm trying to understand their pricing system with dyno, but I don't understand if I buy Standard 2x plan I'll pay 50$ per month or the price can change depand on traffic and then I must buy another dyno for 50$ during that month?

Comment: You pay for the dynos you provision. If your traffic grow, you won't pay anything more if you don't upgrade your dynos. But you will have a slower traffic in this case. You can easily monitor you app activity and change to cheaper/bigger dyno at any time.